# Expression resolves to an unused function

Tags: swift

First of all let me say that I am very new to programming. What I'm trying to do is add a button that when pressed plays music, and when pressed again the music stops. Ideally when the button is pressed for a third time the music will have reset. Whilst trying to achieve this I'm getting the error message "Expression resolves to an unused function", as I am very new all the help I find online doesn't make any sense to me.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var janitor: UIImageView!
    var pianoSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("C", ofType: "m4a")!)
    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: pianoSound, error: nil)
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }


        @IBAction func PianoC(sender: AnyObject) {

        audioPlayer.play()

            if audioPlayer.playing { audioPlayer.stop} else {  audioPlayer.play}
}
}
```

Comment: `stop` --> `stop()`, `play` --> `play()` ...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Swooping in here after Martin R's comment ...

```
if audioPlayer.playing { audioPlayer.stop} else {  audioPlayer.play}
```

On this line, you are not calling the `stop` and `play` functions, but simply accessing them. `Resolving to an unused function` is trying to tell you that you have an expression that is returning a function type, but you are never calling it (`audioPlayer.stop` and `audioPlayer.play` are the expressions in question here).

To rid yourself of this error, and probably produce the correct behavior, try *calling* the functions.

```
if audioPlayer.playing { 
    audioPlayer.stop()
} else {  
    audioPlayer.play()
}
```

Answer (score 10):

**Swift 4:
Just add the braces '()' next to the method name**

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
   addView //error: Expression resolves to an unused function
}

func addView(){
}
```

**Solution:**

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
   addView()
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a simplified version of Brian's answer:

```
audioPlayer.playing
    ? audioPlayer.stop()
    : audioPlayer.play()
```

Comment: @Fr4nc3sc0NL Why's that?

Comment: @RudolfAdamkovic You don't explain what this code is doing

Comment: @grooveplex It's a ternary expression. If the audio player is playing, it will be stopped. If not, it will start playing.

Comment: Its basically shorthand of if else condition. The code translates to -
`If audioPlayer.playing 
        audioPlayer.stop()
else 
        audioPlayer.play()`

Answer (score 0):

`if audioPlayer.playing { audioPlayer.stop} else {  audioPlayer.play}` is just **accessing** the member variables. It's not **doing** anything.

I am sure you're intention was to do audioPlayer.stop() and audioPlayer.start().

However just to explain the ERROR and not to solve your issue: 
had you done something like

```
if audioPlayer.playing { self.playerStatus= audioPlayer.stop} else {  self.playerStatus = audioPlayer.play}
```

Then you were actually *doing* something you were **`set`ting** a parameter. *accessing* or just **`get`ting** a parameter is stupid in the eyes of the compiler :)